# Calculate previous market cap given current market cap and percent change

Tags: linear-algebra

If a company has the market cap $25,750 right now and the `percent_change_24_hrs` is 1.1, how can you calculate what the market cap was 24 hours ago? This should work for both positive and negative % change movements.

I've tried `market_cap * percent_change` but that breaks with negative movements.